# MySQL reinstalling gives error

Tags: mysql

I reinstalled MySQL by following [this guide](http://stuffthatspins.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-10-x-completely-remove-and-clean-mysql-installation/) and after installed it I checked whether the MySQL is ruining by 'service mysql status'. It gives success output.
mysql start/running, process 16959

But when i try to check `mysqladmin -u root -p status`  it gives following error even the correct password provided (which is set in the installation process)

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Please help me to get rid of this error and successfully install MySQL.

Comment: Sounds like everything is fine, but you're not using the right password.

Comment: I entered the right password

Answer (score 0):

Try

> mysql -u username -p

and then enter your password.

If its not working then you need to reset [root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html)